# How to hide and unhide the new VS Code top bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Top bar looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nibk4.png)

I already scoured the internet and found nothing like this question, and no this is not a duplicate question!

Tried all options in VSCode but found nothing to toggle hide or show for this top bar.

I don't like to see the top bar because it occupies real estate in my tiny monitor.